# WSDualHttpBinding in WPF not responding

Tags: wpf, wcf, wsdualhttpbinding, servicebehavior, instancecontextmode

I have problem with using WCF WSDualHttpBinding **only** in WPF application. Before changes this WCF worked. Now not working. I changed only ServiceBehaviour (ConcurrencyMode and InstanceContextMode) to:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
```

After that, WCF not responding, see exception detail. Any ideas?

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
       at MainModuleTracking.GXService.GetServerItemsCompletedEventArgs.get_Result() in d:\Projects\!New!\GXClient\MainModuleTracking.Desktop\Service References\GXService\Reference.cs:line 6274
       at Main.ViewModels.LogOnWindowViewModel.BaseFW_OnGetServerItemsCompleted(Object sender, GetServerItemsCompletedEventArgs e) in d:\Projects\!New!\GXClient\Main.Silverlight\ViewModels\LogOnWindowViewModel.cs:line 208
       at MainModuleTracking.GXService.MainServiceClient.OnGetServerItemsCompleted(Object state) in d:\Projects\!New!\GXClient\MainModuleTracking.Desktop\Service References\GXService\Reference.cs:line 8818
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
       at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
  InnerException: System.TimeoutException
       HResult=-2146233083
       Message=Opening the http://192.168.7.104:8181/WpfMainService channel timed out after 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
         Server stack trace:
            at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeEndService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
         Exception rethrown at [0]:
            at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
            at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
            at MainModuleTracking.GXService.IMainService.EndGetServerItems(IAsyncResult result)
            at MainModuleTracking.GXService.MainServiceClient.EndGetServerItems(IAsyncResult result) in d:\Projects\!New!\GXClient\MainModuleTracking.Desktop\Service References\GXService\Reference.cs:line 8802
            at MainModuleTracking.GXService.MainServiceClient.OnEndGetServerItems(IAsyncResult result) in d:\Projects\!New!\GXClient\MainModuleTracking.Desktop\Service References\GXService\Reference.cs:line 8810
            at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
       InnerException:
```

**EDIT**

```
callbackService = new ServiceCallback();
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callbackService);
mainService = new MainServiceClient(context, "WSDualHttpBinding_IMainService");
mainService.SubscribeErrorsAsync();
mainService.GetServerItemsAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but problem was resolved after time. I think problem was in missing updates.
Now, I tried to used in VS2013 and after build working all perfectly (and without VS2013).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your WCF call is timing out because you have set your WCF server (to essentially) Single access. If you have multiple calls to the service at the same time, your WCF service processes them one at a time, and with your very short timeout, its not surprising that some of them timeout.

Could you explain WHY you changed your ConcurrencyMode?

Comment: I changed ConcurenncyMode because I need one instane by one session for each client. I tried to debug both (client and WCF) on the same time. On the client is created instance of WCF after client call one method. This method make exception - WCF not responding.

Comment: Ok, I make a small application which illustrate problem. Application is in zip here [https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxB1L_GOpVflbk1VMTdZRDdZOUU&usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxB1L_GOpVflbk1VMTdZRDdZOUU&usp=sharing)
In default state - working. If you changed clientBaseAddres to your local adress such as 192.168.1.1 application stop working. So where is problem?